# Firebase Cloud function uses http protocol instead of https

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

My cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log('req protocol: ' + req.protocol + ', secure: ' + req.secure);
    res.send('test');
});
```

When I deploy it, I get an URL link to trigger it, which looks something like this:

```
https://{...}.cloudfunctions.net/test
```

I open this link in a browser, i.e. trigger the function, and see this in Firebase Console log:

[image]

Can you please explain to me, why the request's protocol is not `'https'`?

p.s. This confuses me, because I need to send http request from client's side with sensitive information, and I want to use `https` protocol for that.

Comment: If I check in the browser, the call makes it out securely. My guess is that the traffic gets decrypted somewhere on the Google infrastructure, before it is passed on to your Cloud Functions code.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen: thanks, I guess I'm safe then.